# Want to deploy a Google Cloud Run service via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to deploy a google cloud run service using terraform. When I try to deploy via 'port' block for defining the container port, getting error, I have to pass the container port from template tag but unable to do that. Here is my .tf file -

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-srv"
  location = "us-central1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "us.gcr.io/xxxxxx/xxxx.app"

        port {
          container_port = 19006
        }
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}

data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}

output "url" {
  value = "${google_cloud_run_service.default.status[0].url}"
}
```

With the port tag, here is the error -[image]

And if I not pass the Port block, here is the error - [image]

I have to pass the container port value as 19006 because of my container is running on that port only. How I pass the container port 19006 instead of default port 8080.
[image]

Comment: In your message for the error when the Port block is not passed, there is a comment that the Cloud Logs may contain additional information. Was there anything in those logs of note?

Comment: If you configure your Cloud Run service manually specifying an alternate port, does your solution work?   If you created a gcloud command to create your Cloud Run environment does it work?  If yes, then can you post that exact gcloud command?

Comment: When I create that cloud run service with custom 19006 port manually. It's working. I need to pass the container_port with terraform template. And if am try with gcloud command to deploy my container with custom port, it's deployed successfully.  **gcloud run deploy --image us.gcr.io/xxxxx/xxxxx.app --port 19006**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at REST API exposed by Google for creating a Cloud Run service.

This starts with the entry here:

[POST https://{endpoint}/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/{parent}/services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/create)

where the body contains a [Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#Service).

which contains a [ServiceSpec](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#ServiceSpec)

which contains a [RevisionRemplate](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/RevisionTemplate)

which contains a [RevisionSpec](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/RevisionSpec)

which contains a [Container](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/RevisionSpec#Container)

which contains a [ContainerPort](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/RevisionSpec#ContainerPort)

If we now map this to the source of the Terraform extension to handle creation of Cloud Run Services, we find:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/2dc3da62e3844d14fb2136e09f13ea934b038411/google/resource_cloud_run_service.go#L90

and in the comments, we find the following:

> In the context of a Revision, we disallow a number of the fields of
>   this Container, including: name, ports, and volumeMounts. The runtime
>   contract is documented here:
>   https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/master/docs/runtime-contract.md

While name and volumeMounts seems *ok* to me at this point, I'm not sensing the reason that `ports` are not mapped.

From this though, I seem to see that the inability to specify a port through Terraform seems to be explicit as opposed to an omission.  I also seem to see that the ability to specify a port is indeed present in the REST API at Google.

I was then going to suggest that you raise a defect through Github but then wondered if it was already present.  I did some digging and there is already a request for the missing feature:

[Allow specifying 'container_port' and 'request_timeout' for google_cloud_run_service](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/5539)

My belief is that the core answer to your question then becomes:

> What you are trying to do should work with Terraform and has been
>   raised as an issue and we must wait for the resolution in the
>   Terraform provider.

Comment: @Aniket - Why did you not vote and check this answer? What is still missing?

Comment: It's unfortunate that it's been 1 year and I am still not able to get it to work. I do see a structure for the `ports` block in the docs and even if I follow that, it gives the same error. In the git list of issues, I see a lot of closed issues, but to no avail :sad-face: !

Answer (score 2):

The block should be `ports` (i.e. plural), not `port`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to expose port 9000 and solved it this way:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "service" {
  ...
  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        ...
        ports {
          container_port = 9000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This results in `spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports should contain 0 or 1 port`